# Date format in lightning-input after changed input value format

Tags: lightning-web-components, validation, date, lightninginput

An issue in Date format validation in lightning-input type Date: After I changed the input value format according to the latest Salesforce updated ICU locale format for Ireland.
[image]

The last column shows the latest format above the last line.

The error I'm getting:

[image]

The code that supplies the date value:

JS:

```javascript
this._DOBLife1 = '30/04/1964';
const dobparts = this._DOBLife1.split('/');
this._DOBLife1 = dobparts[0] + ' ' + 'Apr' + ' ' + dobparts[2];
```

HTML:

```html
<lightning-input name="life1_DOB" value={_DOBLife1} class="fieldvalidateterm" type="date" label="DOB"  variant="label-inline" required ></lightning-input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value attribute should be in YYYY-MM-DD format. On view based on locale you can see same date in different formats.

Update js code as below.

```
 this._DOBLife1 = '30/04/1964';
 const dobparts = this._DOBLife1.split('/');
 this._DOBLife1 =  dobparts[2] + '-' + dobparts[1] + '-' + dobparts[0];//Notice this
```

Refer [this](https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-date-in-javascript/) article for more info on dates.